# React forwardRef current null in class component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-forwardref

I'm relatively new to react & can't seem to figure it out, I have researched this for sometime now & nothing seems to work.

I have a parent component where I'm using createRef

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.chartRef = React.createRef();
    }
```

Then pass it to child & access is like following

```
<Grid item xs={12}>
   <Child
      ref={this.chartRef}
    />
    <Button onClick={this.getState}> get ref info</Button>
</Grid>
```

But in getState chartRef current is always null

```
getState = () => {
        console.log(this.chartRef.current);
    };
```

Here is the child component

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.registerPlugins.forEach(plugin => {
            Chart.pluginService.register(plugin);
        });
    }

    render = () => {
        const { data, options, plugins, height } = this.props;

        const updatedOptions = {
            ...options
        };

        return <div>
            <Line
                height={height}
                data={data}
                options={updatedOptions}
                plugins={plugins}/>
        </div>;
    };
}


Child.propTypes = {
    height: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    data: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    options: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    plugins: PropTypes.array,
    registerPlugins: PropTypes.array,
};

export default Child;
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Your question is little bit unclear to me either you are trying to access the parent reference in child or child reference in parent ?

Comment: You seem to have a typo as you are missing closing `>` for Child 
`<Child
      ref={this.chartRef}> 
    </Child>`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I only copied the relevant part to keep things simple & easy to understand & missed the closing bracket while editing, my bad. The code on my side works fine the issue is strictly with ref coming in null. Edited my answer thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @Saad Even in your updated question, the ref seems to bee attached incorrectly. It is hard to provide a solution if your problem can't be reproducible

Comment: Can you create regenerate your problem in codesandbox? Because some of the current answers should have solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the callback style ref E.g.instead of passing your ref as the prop, you can pass in a reference to a function like `this.handleRef`

```
handleRef = r => {
    this.chartRef.current = r;
};

<Child ref={this.handleRef} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access child component in parent with help of reference as like below

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, View } from "react-native";
import Child from "./Child";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.chartRef = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Child ref={(r) => (this.chartRef = r)} />
        <Button
          title="Parent Button"
          onPress={() => {
            console.log(this.chartRef);
          }}
        ></Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

// Child.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "react-native";

export default class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        title="Child Button"
        onPress={() => {
          alert("Child");
        }}
      ></Button>
    );
  }
}
```

you can try this code on [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-mendel-30t25?file=/src/Child.js:0-316)

Comment: It's works on codepen, but when I implemented the exact same thing it still comes out as null. I came across similar solutions during my research but none of them seem to work in my case unfortunately. Thanks for the example